# Samsung Galaxy S10e w/ Android 10: App crashes when keyboard is shown

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-10.0, samsung-galaxy

I have several devices with Android 9, and some now with Android 10.

On a Samsung Galaxy S10e with Android 10 the app crashes, after I edit an EditText and move to the next control, *with my keyboard still open*. It doesn't matter whether I enter text or leave it empty.

On older versions (from 4 to 9), the app works just fine and it also works on another Android 10 device (Nokia 7 plus).

The StackTrace of when my app crashes:

```
java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=16; index=17
        at java.lang.String.substring(String.java:2060)
        at java.lang.String.subSequence(String.java:2107)
        at android.widget.TextView.onProvideStructure(TextView.java:12692)
        at android.view.View.onProvideAutofillStructure(View.java:9211)
        at android.view.View.dispatchProvideStructure(View.java:10092)
        at android.view.View.dispatchProvideAutofillStructure(View.java:10085)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchProvideAutofillStructure(ViewGroup.java:3814)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchProvideAutofillStructure(ViewGroup.java:3814)
        at android.app.assist.AssistStructure$WindowNode.<init>(AssistStructure.java:527)
        at android.app.assist.AssistStructure.<init>(AssistStructure.java:2154)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleRequestAssistContextExtras(ActivityThread.java:3705)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2094)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:237)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7762)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1047)
```

This is the layout for the EditText (The TextChangedListener is never called):

```
<android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/margin_control_large">

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editTextStreet"
        style="?editTextStyle"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:addTextChangedListener="@{viewModel.onStreetChanged}"
        android:cursorVisible="true"
        android:enabled="@{viewModel.newCustomer}"
        android:hint="@string/hint_ebecase_street"
        android:inputType="text"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:singleLine="true"
        android:text="@{viewModel.street}"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmallInverse" />

</android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
```

Comment: Most likely, this is a Samsung bug.

Comment: @abc Did you find any answers? I'm having the same problem.

Comment: @danialiranpour, sorry but not to my knowledge, at least for a few more months. I think there was a workaround by having only a single edittext in our fragment. However I'm not in that company anymore and am not sure about that.

Comment: @abc Actually i fixed this problem by adding `android:importantForAutofill="no"` line to EditText.